# Defining the function's argument type after the ")", is it a very old standard?

Tags: c

I am reading an old book about code obfuscation in C (the book was printed in 1993), and I've noticed that the functions with arguments are implemented this way:

```
real_dump(address, infunc, ofp)
char *address;
int (*infunc)();
FILE *ofp;
{
    /* the code goes here... */
}
```

Also, no return type is defined.

Is it an old standard? Is it possible to enable gcc to compile this code?

Comment: This syntax was old even back in 1993 :)

Comment: I think that the compiler bundled with HP-UX only supports this even on modern systems. The ANSI C compiler costs additional money. So if you need to compile a very simple C program, knowing this syntax can actually be useful.

Comment: In 1993, it was not unreasonable to use that old syntax; there were still machines where the native compilers did not support Standard C.  Not many, but there were some.  It wasn't until the later 90s (say 1996 onwards) that prototypes were sufficiently universal to be usable automatically.  Close to the border, but in 1993, still justifiable (though there should have been a clarification somewhere in the book).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Function definitions in the non-prototype form are valid C89, C99 and C11 code.

It is called the old-style function definition but this feature is marked since C89 as an obsolescent feature.

This form should be **not** used in new programs.

C99 Rationale says:

> "Characterizing the old style as obsolescent is meant to discourage
>   its use and to serve as  a strong endorsement by the Committee of the
>   new style."

even K&R2 discourages its use:

> "The old style of declaration and definition still works with ANSI C, at least for a transition period, but we strongly recommend that you use the new form when you have a compiler that supports it."

Now your function also doesn't have a return type and omitting the return type in a function declaration or in a function definition is no longer valid since C99. Before C99, functions without a return type implicitely returned an `int`.

Regarding the `gcc` question, by default `gcc` compiles with `-std=gnu89`. It means C89 Standard + gcc extensions. So by default `gcc` will accept to compile a program with the functions declaration and definition in their old-style form and without a return type.

Answer (score 9):

Ouch, this was the pre-ANSI C way to define functions, I really don't recommend using this kind of syntax in "normal" code. Still, gcc seems to accept it without problems (it's still in the standard, although marked as "obsolescent" in §6.11.7).

(by the way, as for the "missing" return type the "implicit `int` rule" should apply)

Answer (score 4):

This is the *Kernighan and Ritchie* style of function declaration. K&R C preceded ANSI C, which added the C++-style function prototypes which are most commonly used now.

Answer (score 2):

The lack of return type means the return type is `int`. That's the default.