# Obfuscated Code in C

Tags: c

Please explain how the following snippet of code in C is a valid one

```
int main(c, v) char *v; int c;{
 //program body
}
```

I stumbled across some examples from the International Obfuscated C code contest and i'm just curious.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869768/defining-the-functions-argument-type-after-the-is-it-a-very-old-standard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K&R_C#KRC)-style function declaration. See [Function declaration: K&R vs ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-in-c)

However, I don't believe it has a valid signature for `main()`, since `v` isn't of the right type. See [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

Answer (score 2):

It's the pre-ANSI style of function declaration, if you're referring to why the char*v; int; is outside of the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This is "K&R C", in which function arguments are declared between the end of the argument list and the start of the function's body.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the K&R-style function definition, that, although marked "obsolete", is still allowed by the standard. What is not fine in that code is that the first parameter should be `char **v` (or `char *v[]`) to be standard.